# Push events data to AWS Kinesis Firehose via web client

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a very simple use case of pushing events (click events) from a web browser and storing the data to S3 using AWS kinesis. I'm a bit new to streaming data ingestion so I don't understand the process end-to-end.

I have understood that we can ingest data from a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream to S3 and tested it. It works!

However, I'm unable to understand how to push data from our user's browser to Kinesis Firehose. I have been watching [this official video from AWS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEAJS2FwmDE)  to see how KPL works but the references shown here would basically work in an AWS EC2 instance and attached IAM roles. But my website is hosted on a different cloud.

So, to summarise it, I want my website to push click events to my AWS S3 in near real-time. I want to develop the application in a way that I can just provide some endpoint to the frontend team or similar which they can easily use to push events to the backend. The expected velocity is expected to be 2000 requests/second.
[image]

I think it's a normal use case but since I'm new to streaming data ingestion, that is why I'm facing some issues in understanding the end-to-end flow. AWS has also provided a template for such use cases [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/designing-a-high-volume-streaming-data-ingestion-platform-natively-on-aws/) but not sure if I need everything in the proposed design. Basically, I need to collect the data and store it in S3. We can design the next use cases later. What should be the optimal design (or set of AWS services) for implementing the above-mentioned use case?

Comment: Backend system has no auth and you push events to BE that then forwards onto Kinesis with its own creds - what's the the issue here?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks. Are you talking about a webhook? And what do you mean by BE?